# Paypal reports email address already taken when trying to import test accounts into Paypal Developer tools

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

In paypal developer I created a sandbox account for testing and then deleted it. If I try to create another account using that same email the system seems to think the email I used to create it is still in use? Now I can't use any of the emails that I have used before. Is this a bug or a feature? I reset my browser so I know it's not cookies. Thanks!

Comment: This same problem is happening to me. I'm not sure how this is off topic. (FYI, Paypal's new developer site actually POINTS to these pages on stack overflow) so it might be off topic unintentionally.

Answer (score 2):

Can you share the email address that you are trying to use, and I will see if I can remove it from my side.  What happens, is that when you delete the account it does not actually delete the account.  It only deletes it from your account/view.  It still exists in the system.  If you are going to be using the same email address over and over for accounts you create and delete, just remember to remove the email address on the account prior to deleting it.

Comment: Nice feature -> "..is that when you delete the account it does not actually delete the account.."

Comment: Up. Same problem. I have already used all my emails (legit emails to see paypal's response). How do I reuse them?