# PayPal Sandbox Account - "Email Already Exists"

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

Any way to get around the "Email already exists" when creating a new sandbox account?

I had a user in there, but needed to remove and re-add them. The site was having allot of problems and not sure if that had anything to do with it.

I tried to do the import account, and that didn't work either.

The strange thing is that I could still login to the sandbox site for a while with the account, but now that seems to have stopped working as well.

I would like to be able to re-use this email.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I have the same problem. I've read from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15504742/email-already-exists-error), that this is "by design". I wonder why they do not allow to re-add test accounts. For some reason my test account stopped to work and I decided to re-add it with no luck...

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is a problem. But you don't need to create there a real accounts. Just create something-fake@something.com and when you would need another one add something-fake2@.

The same for customer accounts.